# SSRS: Display Parameters & Network Path on report

Tags: reporting-services

When my report runs, I would like to display on the report:
1. The Parameters that the user selected,
2. The Network Path from which the report was run.

The reports are already displaying Globals!PageNumber of Globals!TotalPages.
I tried using Globals!ReportFolder - but nothing displays.
I also tried CStr(Globals!ReportFolder) - nothing.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have been able to find how to get the Report Parameters onto the report:

Comment: Would appreciate help on how to display the full network path of the location from which the report was run. Thx!